# Cassandra - migrate data folder (change data_file_directories value in config)

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We have a 3-node Cassandra cluster (version 3.16). On one of the node (10.0.4.4) we need to move the data from one drive to another drive on the same node. On SO and other web sites, we have seen the following procedure:

Start by rsyncing the data from old location to new location:

`sudo rsync -avzP --delete /var/lib/cassandra/data /datadrive/cassandra/data`

Repeat until it is fast enough. Then drain & flush the node

```
nodetool flush
nodetool drain
```

Stop cassandra service. We are running it on systemd so we issue

```
sudo systemctl stop cassandra
```

Run again rsync

```
sudo rsync -avzP --delete /var/lib/cassandra/data /datadrive/cassandra/data
```

Update the cassandra.yaml and set data_file_directories:

```
data_file_directories:
  - /datadrive/cassandra/data
```

Ensure permissions are set:

```
chown -R cassandra:cassandra /datadrive/cassandra/data
```

Restart the node:

```
sudo systemctl start cassandra
```

**When doing this sequence, at start-up we get the following error:**

```
ERROR [main] 2020-04-18 14:51:51,742 CassandraDaemon.java:774 - Exception encountered during startup
Apr 18 14:51:51 i1 cassandra: java.lang.RuntimeException: A node with address /10.0.4.4 already exists,
 cancelling join. Use cassandra.replace_address if you want to replace this node.
```

What are we missing? The node is not being replace, so I am hesitant to set replace_address.

What is the right way to change the data folder of a running node that already has data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally found the issue. I am posting the answer as I am thinking it may help people who makes the same mistake. The problem was this line:

```
sudo rsync -avzP --delete /var/lib/cassandra/data /datadrive/cassandra/data
```

The syntax to sync the contents of dir1 to dir2 on the same system is:

```
rsync -r dir1/ dir2
```

Notice the extra **/** after dir1. So the rsync command corrected is:

```
sudo rsync -avzP --delete /var/lib/cassandra/data/ /datadrive/cassandra/data
```

And once this is done, everything works perfectly...